# Why will this php file upload not work?

Tags: php

I have been playing around with this for a while now, but simply cannot get this to upload a submitted file to the server.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php
  if ($_POST["file"]){

    $allowedExts = array("mp3", "txt");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                     "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }

  }
?>
```

Comment: what is your form html?

Comment: Yes. Also i should have said i am testing it with a text file.

Comment: What's the problem here?  Do you get any errors?  What gets echoed?  How are you uploading the file?  We need more details.

Comment: change `if($_POST["file"]){` to `if($_FILES["file"]){`

Comment: Nothing gets echoed. It just doesn't do anything. What is missing to make it upload the file?

Comment: @user2023307 try my suggestion...

Comment: @Akam: I'd suggest `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){`

Comment: Akam = Hero. Thank you Sir.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" ??

Comment: I am using   
enctype="multipart/form-data" ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your form has enctype...

```
<form action=".." method=".." enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, "if ($_POST["file"]){" -> this works only if your submit button's name is "file", if your input type=file tag has name "file" it should be: if(isset($_FILES["file"]))

Answer (score -1):

You should check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`, as it will return FALSE if it failed to move the file for any reason. If you have warnings turned on, then PHP will issue a warning giving you more information about why it failed. You can turn warnings on by using the following code at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Is your upload directory writable? If it is not writable then, obviously, `move_uploaded_file` will fail.

Edit:

As another user pointed out, the `if ($_POST["file"])` line needs to be `if ($_FILES["file"])`. That may be all that is wrong.

Comment: As another user pointed out, the if ($_POST["file"]) line needs to be if ($_FILES["file"]). That may be all that is wrong. This was indeed the problem. Thanks for the help all.